# mysql nested query gets syntax error

Tags: mysql

My Questions are:

1. Student's reg_id who took highest total marks.
2. Students' reg_ids who
   took highest for subject vice.

There exists a table "students" with attributes (reg_id,subject,marks) .

There are 8 subjects, each student take all 8 subjects. So the table consists 8 records per student.no of students depends. for eg: 10 students so, total no.of.records = 8*10 =80.

Here are my queries. Please someone correct what is wrong with it.Thank you.

```
1)"select A.reg_id from (select S.reg_id, sum(S.marks) as total from students S group by S.reg_id) as A where A.total=(select max(C.total) from (select S1.reg_id,sum(S1.marks) as total from students S1 group by S1.reg_id) as C);"

2)"select A.reg_id from (select S.reg_id, sum(S.marks) as total from students S group by S.reg_id) as A where A.total=(select max(A.total) from A);"`
```

error message :

```
ERROR 1064 (HY000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select S.reg_id, sum(S.marks) as total from
students S group by
Student's reg_id who took highest total marks : 
 Students' reg_ids who took highest for subject vice : reg_id subject max(s.marks) id1 Buddhist 99 id1 computer 81 id1 English 95 id5 History 82 id1 Literature 95 id1 Maths 97 id1 Sinhala 85 id9 Social 90
```

second one, i get the answer but not with the right values.

Comment: Can you please post the errormessage

Comment: ERROR 1064 (HY000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select S.reg_id, sum(S.marks) as total from
students S group by
Student's reg_id who took highest total marks : 
 Students' reg_ids who took highest for subject vice : reg_id `subject max(s.marks) id1 Buddhist 99 id1 computer 81 id1 English 95 id5 History 82 id1 Literature 95 id1 Maths 97 id1 Sinhala 85 id9 Social 90`

Comment: second one, i get the answer but with wrong values :(

Comment: In the first Query I think you must have one `(` more before `((select S.reg_id, `

Comment: nested query is very complex

Comment: no.. curly brackets are closed properly i think ..

Comment: what output exactly you want?

Answer (score 0):

you change like below:

```
select A.reg_id from (select S.reg_id, sum(S.marks) as total from students S group by S.reg_id) as A where A.total IN (select max(C.total) from (select S1.reg_id,sum(S1.marks) as total from students S1 group by S1.reg_id) as C);

select A.reg_id from (select S.reg_id, sum(S.marks) as total from students S group by S.reg_id) as A where A.total IN (select max(A.total) from A);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
      Select reg_id, max (total) as maxtotal from (
        select reg_id, sum(marks) as total from students S    group by reg_id ) t
```